# Set printf() value in a PHP variable

Tags: php, printf, floating

I have a php script that show a time like: 9.08374786377E-5 , but i need plain floating value as a time like : 0.00009083747..... Thats why i just print it with float like that:

```
<?php

function microtime_float()
{
list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
$time_start = microtime_float();

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
printf('%.16f', $time);

?>
```

Its show the result nicely, but i need to set this printing value in a new variable. how can i do that ? I need to set this printing value in a new variable $var;

```
$var = printf('%.16f', $time);
```

// We all know its not working, but how to set ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to use the [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) command to get your data as a variable... printf outputs the results whereas sprintf returns the results

```
$var = sprintf('%.16f', $time);
```

Answer (score 4):

That's because [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) returns a string, [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) displays it.

```
printf('%.16f', $time);
```

is the same as:

```
echo sprintf('%.16f', $time);
```

Since `sprintf()` prints the result to a string, you can store it in a variable like so:

```
$var = sprintf('%.16f', $time);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, `printf()` is the same as `echo sprintf()`

Comment: @SauloPadilha Ah, I missed that. Fixed it; thanks for the heads-up!